# How can I open this GoPro folder using the command line? (Windows 10)

Tags: windows, usb, path, portable

When I plug in my GoPro camera via USB, I have to click through four folders before I get to the folder where the video files are:

`This PC\HERO8 BLACK\GoPro MTP Client Disk Volume\DCIM\100GOPRO`

`100GOPRO` is where the video files are. I tried to make a shortcut to this folder but Windows doesn't let me - no shortcut is created when I try to drag the icon from the address bar to my desktop.

I created a batch file telling explorer to open the folder, but the path starts with "This PC" as opposed to a drive letter. I tried this in a batch file:

`explorer "This PC\HERO8 BLACK\GoPro MTP Client Disk Volume\DCIM\100GOPRO"`

Doesn't work, that just opens My Documents (the default folder when it can't find a path).

This GoPro is classed as an "MTP USB Device" when I look in Device Manager in Windows. The driver is up to date.

This limitation also means I can't copy the video files from the device using a batch file either, which would be really convenient if it was possible.

Unless there's some magic code for the parent folder "This PC" it seems this can't be done?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I tried this and it doesn't work either:

`explorer "shell:mycomputerfolder\HERO8 BLACK\GoPro MTP Client Disk Volume\DCIM\100GOPRO"`

What I can do is right click the `HERO8 BLACK` icon in "This PC" and create shortcut, it says it can't create a shortcut there so would I like it to be placed on the Desktop - yes - then I do have a shortcut to that device on the desktop but, I cannot edit the path in the properties of that shortcut to add the rest of the path to it (it's greyed out) otherwise it would work.

I know I'm swapping between asking how to open the folder on the command line and opening it via a shortcut but it doesn't matter which way I do it, I just want to run something once and have the final folder opening. It's better if it's on the command line because then I could use that to also create a command to copy the files to the folder where the batch file is run.

Comment: I used a workaround by using AutoIt to do it but it's creating clutter to do it and needs AutoIt installed (if you ever want to edit the script, for example if the Hero 9 camera is plugged in you'd need the script to be different). Still want to solve this using a batch file to directly open the folder if it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I managed to do this, without using AutoIt. This is a far cleaner way and it is a one-click solution once you set the device name and path:

Put this in a batch file:

```
:: Put the device name from "This PC" here inside the double quotes:
set DEVICE_NAME="HERO8 BLACK"

:: Put the device folder path (the part after the device name in "This PC") here inside the double quotes:
set DEVICE_FOLDER_PATH="GoPro MTP Client Disk Volume\DCIM\100GOPRO"

:: Copy MP4 files from Device
start /wait /min Powershell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& '%~dp0CFD.ps1' -deviceName '%DEVICE_NAME%' -deviceFolder '%DEVICE_FOLDER_PATH%' -targetFolder '%CD%' -filter '(.mp4)$'"
```

Create a Powershell script called `CFD.ps1` and put this in:

```
# Windows Powershell Script to copy a set of files (based on a filter) from a folder
# on a MTP device (e.g. Android device) to a folder on a computer, using the Windows Shell.
# By Daiyan Yingyu, 19 March 2018, based on the (non-working) script found here:
#   https://www.pstips.net/access-file-system-against-mtp-connection.html
# as referenced here:
#   https://powershell.org/forums/topic/powershell-mtp-connections/
#
# This Powershell script is provided 'as-is', without any express or implied warranty.
# In no event will the author be held liable for any damages arising from the use of this script.
#
# Please note that used 'as-is' this script will COPY files from you device.
# If you want to move files instead, you can replace the CopyHere function call with "MoveHere" instead.
# WARNING: The files will be DELETED from the source (the device) and MOVED to the computer.
# But once again, the author can take no responsibility for the use, or misuse, of this script.</em>
#
param([string]$deviceName,[string]$deviceFolder,[string]$targetFolder,[string]$filter='(.jpg)|(.mp4)$')
 
function Get-ShellProxy
{
    if( -not $global:ShellProxy)
    {
        $global:ShellProxy = new-object -com Shell.Application
    }
    $global:ShellProxy
}
 
function Get-Device
{
    param($deviceName)
    $shell = Get-ShellProxy
    # 17 (0x11) = ssfDRIVES from the ShellSpecialFolderConstants (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774096(v=vs.85).aspx)
    # => "My Computer" — the virtual folder that contains everything on the local computer: storage devices, printers, and Control Panel.
    # This folder can also contain mapped network drives.
    $shellItem = $shell.NameSpace(17).self
    $device = $shellItem.GetFolder.items() | where { $_.name -eq $deviceName }
    return $device
}
 
function Get-SubFolder
{
    param($parent,[string]$path)
    $pathParts = @( $path.Split([system.io.path]::DirectorySeparatorChar) )
    $current = $parent
    foreach ($pathPart in $pathParts)
    {
        if ($pathPart)
        {
            $current = $current.GetFolder.items() | where { $_.Name -eq $pathPart }
        }
    }
    return $current
}
 
$deviceFolderPath = $deviceFolder
$destinationFolderPath = $targetFolder
# Optionally add additional sub-folders to the destination path, such as one based on date
 
$device = Get-Device -deviceName $deviceName
$folder = Get-SubFolder -parent $device -path $deviceFolderPath
 
$items = @( $folder.GetFolder.items() | where { $_.Name -match $filter } )
if ($items)
{
    $totalItems = $items.count
    if ($totalItems -gt 0)
    {
        # If destination path doesn't exist, create it only if we have some items to move
        if (-not (test-path $destinationFolderPath) )
        {
            $created = new-item -itemtype directory -path $destinationFolderPath
        }
 
        Write-Verbose "Processing Path : $deviceName\$deviceFolderPath"
        Write-Verbose "Moving to : $destinationFolderPath"
 
        $shell = Get-ShellProxy
        $destinationFolder = $shell.Namespace($destinationFolderPath).self
        $count = 0;
        foreach ($item in $items)
        {
            $fileName = $item.Name
 
            ++$count
            $percent = [int](($count * 100) / $totalItems)
            Write-Progress -Activity "Processing Files in $deviceName\$deviceFolderPath" `
                -status "Processing File ${count} / ${totalItems} (${percent}%)" `
                -CurrentOperation $fileName `
                -PercentComplete $percent
 
            # Check the target file doesn't exist:
            $targetFilePath = join-path -path $destinationFolderPath -childPath $fileName
            if (test-path -path $targetFilePath)
            {
                write-error "Destination file exists - file not moved:`n`t$targetFilePath"
            }
            else
            {
                $destinationFolder.GetFolder.CopyHere($item)
                if (test-path -path $targetFilePath)
                {
                    # Optionally do something with the file, such as modify the name (e.g. removed device-added prefix, etc.)
                }
                else
                {
                    write-error "Failed to move file to destination:`n`t$targetFilePath"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As long as the 2 variables are set properly at the top of the first file (the batch file) and you have put `CFD.ps1` next to the batch file, this works to copy the device's MP4 files to the same folder as the batch file and ps1 script.

It's also possible to copy both jpg and mp4 files, or only jpg files, but that needs slightly different commands in the batch file:

Copy JPG and MP4 files:

```
start /wait /min Powershell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& '%~dp0CFD.ps1' -deviceName '%DEVICE_NAME%' -deviceFolder '%DEVICE_FOLDER_PATH%' -targetFolder '%CD%\Files' -filter '(.jpg)|(.mp4)$'"
```

Only copy JPG files:

```
start /wait /min Powershell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& '%~dp0CFD.ps1' -deviceName '%DEVICE_NAME%' -deviceFolder '%DEVICE_FOLDER_PATH%' -targetFolder '%CD%\Files' -filter '(.jpg)$'"
```

The original ps1 script actually moved the files from the device, which isn't the intention in the above script (it copies).

To move the files, change `CopyHere` to `MoveHere` on line 98 of the ps1 script.

Anything else... I have no idea. Look how long that ps1 script has to be for such a simple task! All because the device doesn't have a drive letter.

Using this, you can apply it to any MTP device as long as you put the correct device name and path at the start of the batch file. The ps1 script can stay unaltered.